# Get CSV Data from Blob Storage to SQL server Using ADF

Tags: sql, azure, csv, azure-blob-storage, ssms

I want to transfer data from csv file which is in an azure blob storage with the correct data types to SQL server table.
How can I get the structure for the table in the CSV file? ( I mean like when we do script table to new query in SSMS).
Note that the CSV file is not available on premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **target table is already created in SSMS**, copy activity will take care of the schema of source and target tables.

This is my sample csv file from blob:

[image]

In the sink I have used a table from Azure SQL database. For you, you can create SQL server dataset by SQL server linked service.

[image]

You can see the schema of csv and target tables and their mapping.

[image]

Result:

[image]

if your **target table is not created in SSMS**, you can use **dataflows and can define the schema that you want in the Projection**.

Create a data flow and in the sink give our blob csv file. In the projection of sink, we can give the datatypes that we want for the csv file.

[image]

As our target table is not created before, check on edit in the dataset and give the name for the table.

[image]

In the sink, give this dataset (SQL server dataset in your case) and make sure you check on the Recreate table in the sink Settings, so that a new table with that name will be created.

[image]

Execute this Dataflow, your target table will be created with your user defined data types.